How to uniformly sample from space of orthonormal matrices
A simple way of generating a random orthonormal matrix is to first sample a random matrix and subsequently apply the singular value decomposition
def random_orthonormal_matrix(n):
    random_matrix = np.random.normal(0., 1., (n, n))
    u, _, _ = np.linalg.svd(random_matrix)
    return u

However, using this procedure seems to limit the space from which orthonormal matrices are sampled as n increases. In particular, it seems like matrices become less and less likely to be sampled from either end of the extremes, i.e., close to the identity or the negative of the identity matrix:
def cosine_similarity(A, B):
    norm_A = np.linalg.norm(A)
    norm_B = np.linalg.norm(B)
    
    return np.dot(A.flatten(), B.flatten()) / (norm_A * norm_B)

for n in range(4, 33, 4):
    similarities = []
    I = np.identity(items_n)
    for _ in range(100000):
        U = random_orthonormal_matrix(n)
        similarities.append(cosine_similarity(U, I))
    print(np.min(similarities), np.max(similarities))

Generates output
-0.9512750256370359 0.9196429830937393
-0.5402804372155989 0.5641902334710601
-0.33279493103542684 0.3570616519070167
-0.26855564226727774 0.26038092858834694
-0.24803547122804348 0.21364982076125164
-0.18041307918712912 0.18015163443704285
-0.1502303153596804 0.15272379170859116
-0.13915507336472144 0.13962760476513508

How can this procedure be modified, such that the expected distance to the identity matrix is uniform for any n? And further, is it possible to directly generate a random orthonormal matrix for a given distance d?

You say you want uniformity, but you're using numpy.random.normal which yields a Gaussian (bell-shaped) distribution. As an aside, the numpy docs say "New code should use the normal method of a Generator instance instead".

@pjs Thing is, the distribution of a random vector with Gaussian components is isotropic (i.e. invariant by rotations), because exp(-x²)*exp(-x²)*exp(-x²) = exp(-r²). The distribution of a vector with uniform components is some hypercube which is NOT isotropic . For a full explanation, see the paper by Mezzadri where he does start from Gaussian components to generate Haar measure compliant unitary random matrices.

@Genius Are you suspecting that your matrices are not evenly (Haar measure) distributed ? Or do you have a reason to want some distribution that differs from the standard Haar measure ?

you have bug in the code, it doesn't work

Mezzadri algorithm is already implemented in SciPy, see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ortho_group.html for details
So if you replace your def random_orthonormal_matrix(n) with
from scipy.stats import ortho_group
def random_orthonormal_matrix(n):
    return ortho_group.rvs(dim=n)

then you supposed to get what you want. For complex matrices from U(n) there is
scipy.stats.unitary_group with the same/similar implementation, see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.unitary_group.html for details.
Not sure how to implement sampling you want - specific distance using specific measure
